# Removing Header and Footer from imported .csv

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have 3 .csv files that I am combining into one.  This bit of code works:

```
    Get-ChildItem 'C:\Scripts\testing\csvStuffer\temp\Individual.*.csv' | 
        ForEach-Object {Import-Csv $_} | 
        Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation 'C:\Scripts\testing\csvStuffer\temp\MergedCsvFiles.csv'
```

The problem is that each .csv file has a header and a footer.
I do not want to keep the header or footer from any of the files.
Any suggestions of what I need to add to the above code to remove the headers and footers???
Thanks!

Comment: Footers are not valid in a CSV so that is your first problem. Are the headers the same in each file?

Comment: Maybe I should have said Firstline and Lastline.  No, they are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution but it worked for my test files.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Scripts\testing\csvStuffer\temp\Individual.*.csv' | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $filecontent = get-content $_ | select-object -skip 1;
            $filecontent | select -First $($filecontent.length -1) | Set-Content -Path $_;
        };
```

Skipping the first line is easy with `select-object`. Dropping the last line requires a bit more work, but since `get-content` returns an array of lines, you can just grab all but the last element in that array.

Comment: You can grab all but the first and last line with something like: $array[1..($array.count -1)]

Comment: This does not write out to a new file and append, it removes a line from each file each time it is run??

Comment: This works.  Thanks!!!                                             Get-ChildItem $PathToFiles | 
        ForEach-Object {$filecontent = get-content $_ | select-object -skip 1;$filecontent | select -First $($filecontent.length -1) |  Out-File $OutputFile -Append}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like alroc already gave an answer, but since I already had it written up I figured I'd post this too. It doesn't load it all into a variable, it just reads each file, strips the first and last line of the current file, and then pipes to out-file with -append on it.

```
gci 'C:\Scripts\testing\csvStuffer\temp\Individual.*.csv' | %{
$(gc $_.fullname|skip 1)|select -First ($(gc $_.fullname|skip 1).count-1)
}|Out-File -Append 'C:\Scripts\testing\csvStuffer\temp\MergedCsvFiles.csv'
```

Comment: This errors:  ObjectNotFound: (skip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

Comment: What version of powershell? This script works perfectly on my machine, maybe it's a version conflict?

Comment: I have version 4 installed

Comment: Are you using that code copy & paste, or can you update your question to reflect what you're using now?